# how can multiple values be inserted in a table skipping few values in mysql

Tags: mysql

I can enforce data restriction at the time of data insertion in a table using a trigger like following:

```
create table com(id int);

DELIMITER ;; 
CREATE TRIGGER checkage_bi BEFORE INSERT ON com FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN  
DECLARE dummy,baddata INT;  
SET baddata = 0;
IF NEW.id > 20 THEN 
    SET baddata = 1; 
END IF; 
IF NEW.id < 1 THEN 
    SET baddata = 1;  
END IF;  
IF baddata = 1 THEN  
    SELECT CONCAT('Cannot Insert This Because id ',NEW.id,' is Invalid') 
    INTO dummy FROM information_schema.tables;
END IF;
END;;
```

this will restrict the values which will not meet the restriction condition.
But the problem is that if I insert multiple values along then for some values which do not meet the condition the other values will also be restricted from entry to table.

What I want is that when I insert multiple values along then the values that do not meet the  condition should be skipped and the rest get inserted into the table

i.e. no any error is given.

Only the the bad values will be skipped and the other values will be inserted that's it.

Please give me some idea to do so.Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

You should better use stored Procedures rather than triggers for this purpose because you are not permitted within a stored function or trigger to modify a table that is already being used (for reading or writing) by the statement that invoked the function or trigger itself.

```
DELIMITER ;; 
create table com(id int,var char(40));;

create procedure Validate(IN id int,IN var char(40))
BEGIN
declare entry_id int;
SET entry_id=id;
IF (id > 20) OR (id < 1) THEN 
 SET entry_id=NULL;
END IF; 
insert into com values(entry_id,var);
END;;
```

Here is the output screen

[image: output]